# \foreach loop doesn't work with \input

Tags: foreach

The result of this:

```
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{% 
\x
}
```

and this one are the same:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}{%
1,2,3%
}

\foreach \x in \mycommand{% 
\x
}
```

However if i make a "example.tex" file which includes 1,2,3 then this doesnt work:

```
\foreach \x in \input{example}{% 
\x
}
```

I will make a lot of "example1.tex", "example2.tex" etc. files and want to be able to choose one of them to iterate through.

Is there a workaround? I need to combine foreach (or something similar) to input.

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the file contents in a temporary macro, with the help of `catchfile`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-example}
1,2,3
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\foreachinfile}[2]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\foreachinfiletemp}{#2}{}%
  \foreach #1 in \foreachinfiletemp
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,2,3} {\x}

\foreachinfile \x {\jobname-example} {\x}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach with `expl3`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-example}
1,2,3
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__bilal_xforeach_tl
\clist_new:N \l__bilal_xforeach_clist

\keys_define:nn { bilal/xforeach }
 {
  list .clist_set:N = \l__bilal_xforeach_clist,
  macro .code:n = \clist_set:NV \l__bilal_xforeach_clist #1,
  file .code:n = \file_get:nnN { #1 } { } \l__bilal_xforeach_tl
                 \clist_set:NV \l__bilal_xforeach_clist \l__bilal_xforeach_tl,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\xforeach}{mm}
 {% #1 = list, macro or file; #2 = template
  \keys_set:nn { bilal/xforeach } { #1 }
  \cs_set:Nn \__bilal_xforeach:n { #2 }
  \clist_map_function:NN \l__bilal_xforeach_clist \__bilal_xforeach:n
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\test}{1,2,3}

\begin{document}

\xforeach{list={1,2,3}}{#1}

\xforeach{macro=\test}{#1}

\xforeach{file=\jobname-example}{#1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second argument to `\xforeach` is a template, where the current item in the loop is denoted by `#1`.

Comment: I need a lot of ".tex" files in my folder and want to be able to choose one of them to iterate through

Comment: @BilalYilmaz I used `filecontents` just to make the example self-contained. You don't need it yourself.

Comment: It works fine thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This answer mimics that of egreg, but uses the `readarray` package to absorb the input file into a macro.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.dat}
1,2,3
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{readarray}

\newcommand{\foreachinfile}[2]{%
  \readdef{#2}{\foreachinfiletemp}%
  \foreach #1 in \foreachinfiletemp
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,2,3} {\x}

\foreachinfile \x {mydata.dat} {\x}

\end{document}
```

If the inputs are not comma separated but placed separately, one per file record, the use of `\readarraysepchar{,}` can be used to artificially insert a comma after each record, so that the same result can be achieved:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.dat}
1
2
3
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{readarray}

\newcommand{\foreachinfile}[2]{%
  \readdef{#2}{\foreachinfiletemp}%
  \foreach #1 in \foreachinfiletemp
}

\readarraysepchar{,}
\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,2,3} {\x}

\foreachinfile \x {mydata.dat} {\x}

\end{document}
```

In either case, the result is

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with [overwrite]{mydata.dat} ?

Comment: @BilalYilmaz The `filecontents` environment is a way to create a data file from within LaTeX.  If you have existing data files, you can just remove the `filecontents` code from your own.  In my case, I needed it, because I did not have an existing data file for input.  The `overwrite` option of that environment tells latex that if that data file already exists, overwrite it with the data specified in the environment.

Comment: I see, thanks! I implemented your code. The problem is, if i have a file name with space something like "bla bla.tex" then it seems that it doesnt work. (i mean your second code with \readarraysepchar{,}). Is this normal?

Comment: @BilalYilmaz You can either use `\foreachinfile \x {"my data.dat"} {\x}` with quotes, to invoke the command, or redefine the command (with quotes) to change the line `\readdef{"#2"}{\foreachinfiletemp}`.  Obviously, in this case, the `filecontents` created must also have the space: `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{my data.dat}`

Comment: Thanks a lot i will check!